# MockResolvedValueOnce require type never even though mocked function must return string

Tags: typescript, nestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to test NestJS and this is a real challenge I must say. Thanks to people from Here I managed how to build structure of test code but still face couple of problems. One of those is the mocked function must return `string`, but TypeScript shows it must be type `never`

```
(method) jest.MockInstance<string, [expression: string]>.mockResolvedValueOnce(value:
 never): ((expression: string) => string) & jest.MockWithArgs<(expression: string) =>
 string> & {}

// here is the part of code with Error

service.getResult.mockResolvedValueOnce('2+2');
```

**Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.**

Let's take a look at the whole testing Module

```
describe('CaclulatorController', () => {
  let controller: CalculatorController;
  let service: Pick<jest.MockedObject<CalculatorService>, 'getResult'>;
  let cache: Pick<
    jest.MockedObject<CacheService>,
    'checkInCache' | 'setToCache'
  >;
  let history: Pick<jest.MockedObject<HistoryService>, 'create'>;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const modRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [CalculatorController],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: CALCULATOR_SERVICE,
          useValue: {
            getResult: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
        {
          provide: CACHE_SERVICE,
          useValue: {
            checkInCache: jest.fn(),
            setToCache: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
        {
          provide: HISTORY_SERVICE,
          useValue: {
            create: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    controller = modRef.get(CalculatorController);
    service = modRef.get(CALCULATOR_SERVICE);
    cache = modRef.get(CACHE_SERVICE);
    history = modRef.get(HISTORY_SERVICE);
  });

 describe('getResult', () => {
    it('should get no response from the cache and perform a full caclulation', async () => {
      const dbResponse = {
        expression: '2+2+2*3',
        result: '10',
        _id: '63ecf3c0ca3cb4911dc5f013',
      };
      cache.checkInCache.mockResolvedValueOnce(undefined);
      service.getResult.mockResolvedValueOnce('2+2+2*3'); //PROBLEM!!!
      history.create.mockResolvedValueOnce(); //HERE AS WELL, Actually this func mus return Promise
      cache.setToCache.mockResolvedValueOnce({
        expression: '2+2+2*3',
        result: '10',
        _id: '63ecf3c0ca3cb4911dc5f013',
      });
      await expect(
        controller.getResult({ expression: '2+2+2*3' }),
      ).resolves.toEqual(dbResponse);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you show the actual definitions of the `CalculatorService#getResult` and `HistoryService#create` methods in your question? I may have given bad mocks in your previous question based on what I thought I saw

Comment: @JayMcDoniel, thanks once again! I will delete the question or you may answer it if you want. I've found that ```mockResolvedOnce``` should return from function which is asynchronous, but if the function is not so we should use ```mockReturnValue```